# Find First Non-Empty Value in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, string

I am having trouble trying to grab the first non empty value in my xml file.

Here is the what the XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>
<Student>
    <Student_id>TEST1</Student_id>
    <last_printed>2014-03-11-08:00</last_printed>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Student_id>TEST3</Student_id>
    <last_printed></last_printed>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Student_id>TEST4</Student_id>
    <last_printed>2014-03-06-08:00</last_printed>
</Student>
</ROOT>
```

I am trying to grab the first `<last_printed>` element parse out the date using this XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(/ROOT/Student[1]/last_printed[text() != ''], '-'), '-'), '-')"/>
<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after(/ROOT/Student[1]/last_printed[text() != ''], '-'), '-')"/>
<xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before(/ROOT/Student[1]/last_printed[text() != ''], '-')"/>
```

The end result being a date displayed MMDDYYYY:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($month, $day, $year, $padding), 1, 8)"/>
```

I tried placing the index `[1]` on the Student element in the variable statement as shown above, I also tried putting it here:

```
<xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before(/ROOT/Student/last_printed[1][text() != ''], '-')"/>
```

If I don't include the `[1]`, I get an error stating:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after("2014-03-06-08:00", "2014-03-11-08:00")

It grabs all date values in the XML.

With the `[1]`, it looks like the XSLT is grabbing the first element it comes across, but it is grabbing an empty element.

How can I grab the first non-empty element. I thought the `[text() != '']` would help, but it does not.

Comment: Your XML's invalid; the `</Student>` after `<ROOT>`

Comment: @Utkanos - Sorry, copy and paste error.

Comment: Seems OK to me - http://www.xmlplayground.com/lTakkR

Comment: It's working for me as well. Perhaps you had an empty `Student` element before, and that was causing the error.

Comment: Actually, the predicate is not even necessary, since there is only one `last_printed` in `Student[1]`

Comment: http://xsltcake.com/slices/7tAcOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Try starting with:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstDate" select="/ROOT/Student[last_printed/text()][1]/last_printed" />
```

Now you have the first (in document order!) non-empty value and you can proceed to reformat it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

How about simply writing a template to match the said element?

```
<xsl:template match="last_printed[text() and not(preceding::last_printed/text())]">
```

This finds the first `last_printed` element that has text nodes, that is, which is not preceded by another `last_printed` element that has text nodes.

---

I cannot reproduce the error you get, but this:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after("2014-03-06-08:00", "2014-03-11-08:00")

clearly means that your are supplying a *sequence* of strings as the first argument of a string function (the message is about `substring-after`, your code only mentions `substring-before`).

So, you'll have to study your code closely to find a line where there could potentially be more than one match.

And another thing. When using `element[text() != '']`, you assume that *all* elements have text nodes, but some of them are empty, or are equal to `''`.

But this is not true. If elements do not have textual content, they don't have text nodes either. Therefore, a condition like

```
<xsl:if test="element[text() != '']">
```

returns "false" for empty elements because text nodes are non-existent, not because they are empty strings. As a consequence of this,

```
<xsl:if test="element[text()]">
```

is essentially the same.